# Как поменять пароль от админки в joomla 3?

Tags: joomla, cms, password-hash

Пробовал через [phpmyadmin](https://joomla.shneider-host.ru/blog/obshchie-voprosy-dzhumla/kak-vosstanovit-parol-administratora-joomla), но не выходит.

Есть еще варианты?)

Answer (score 2):

Еще один вариант. Если пароль не шифруется с md5 а шифруется более сложнее.

1. Регистрируемся как новый пользователь (логин и пароли новые).
2. Заходим в `phpmyadmin` и находим этого нового пользователя.
3. Копируем его пароль (уже зашифрованном виде).
4. Находим администратора и заменяем его пароль с скопированным.

Все должно работать.

Comment: Если логин не входит в соль.

Comment: не понял, что такое соль?

Comment: В криптографии соль (модификатор) — это строка случайных данных, которая подается на вход хеш-функции вместе с исходными данными. Используется для удлинения строки пароля, что осложняет восстановление группы исходных паролей за один проход полного перебора или с помощью предварительно построенных радужных таблиц. (c) Википедия

Comment: аа это, ну да вы правы. тогда нужно будет 2 копию joomla поднять с другой базы, установить пароль для админа, и его использовать для замены.

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin -> находим таблицу [префикс]_users -> вводим 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70 в качестве пароля для нужного пользователя -> сохраняем и заходим в админку - [имя пользователя] / 123

Answer (score 0):

Выполните следующий SQL запрос который присвоит пароль **admin** пользователю с логином **admin**:

```
UPDATE joomla3_users SET password='dc85820626dbd8936f17667eb01c30de:N16Ehwv77HlgxEL81V7Ox3mOgZlRFwrI' WHERE username='admin';
```

Далее установите необходимый пароль через административную часть.

Возможно вам потребуется заменить следующие значения в запросе:

admin - логин администратора

joomla3 - префикс таблиц

Текущий префикс таблиц можно найти в файле **configuration.php** строка `public $dbprefix = 'ваш_префикс'`

Answer (score -1):

Новый пароль необходимо шифровать. Ты явно что-то упустил :) для простоты используй сторонний ресурс. Шифрователей md-5 великое множество.[к примеру](http://pr-cy.ru/md5/) один из них. Полученный результат уже вставляй в май админе

Comment: Хеширование - это не шифрование.